# How to react on link remove event in JointJS

Tags: jointjs

I use the following code to control the remove functionality on links. How can I intercept the remove event and prevent it if the link match a specific condition?

```
// add a remove button on hovered link
this.paper.on("link:mouseenter", function(linkView) {
  let tools = [new joint.linkTools.Remove({ distance: 20 })];

  linkView.addTools(
    new joint.dia.ToolsView({
      name: "onhover",
      tools: tools
    })
  );
});

// remove button on hovered link
this.paper.on("link:mouseleave", function(linkView) {
  if (!linkView.hasTools("onhover")) return;
  linkView.removeTools();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer by using the action argument passed to the linkTools.Remove constructor.

```
// add a remove button on hovered link
this.paper.on("link:mouseenter", function(linkView) {
  let tools = [
    new joint.linkTools.Remove({
      distance: 20,
      action: function(evt) {
        // do stuff and remove link using
        this.model.remove({ ui: true, tool: this.cid });
      }
    })
  ];

  linkView.addTools(
    new joint.dia.ToolsView({
      name: "onhover",
      tools: tools
    })
  );
});
```